# Post data to google spreedsheet using php

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script

I am trying to post data using curl php but the issue I am facing the data saved in Google sheet is always coming undefined. I have used below code which is attached with description and also attached the image url which is showing the value coming from is php script I am using php and curl to send data and trying to savethat data in google sheet.

Image showing undefined value: https://ibb.co/0n5WKdz

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
function send_to_url($url, $data)
{
$ch = curl_init($url);
//Set a POST method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);

//Set data to JSON application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//POST to URL
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//Get result from POST if any
$result_post = urldecode(json_encode($result));

curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$users = 
array("Date"=>"Timestamp","FirstName"=>"John","LastName"=>"Cena","Email"=>"john78@example.com");
send_to_url("GOOGLE_APP_SCRIPT_URL",$users);
```

**GOOGLE SCRIPT**

```
var SHEET_NAME = "DATA";
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {

  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": headRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Please check my code and provide the solution and let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your scripts, I think that your php script works and Google Apps Script is required to be modified a little. So how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

1. When a JSON object (`{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`) is sent to Web Apps as POST request, `e` of `doPost(e)` becomes as follows.

   ```
   {
     "parameter": {},
     "contextPath": "",
     "contentLength": 36,
     "queryString": "",
     "parameters": {},
     "postData": {
       "type": "application/json",
       "length": 36,
       "contents": "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}",
       "name": "postData"
     }
   }
   ```

   By this, when you want to retrieve the values from the object, the object is required to be parsed like `var postData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)`. It seems that although the data is sent as `application/json`, the object is not automatically parsed.
2. About the line of `if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){`, your sample image doesn't have `Timestamp`. I thought that it might be `Date`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var row = []; 
// loop through the header columns
for (i in headers){
  if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
    row.push(new Date());
  } else { // else use header name to get data
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
  }
}
```

To:

```
var postData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var row = headers.map(function(e) {return e == "Date" ? new Date() : postData[e]});
```

#### Result:

When your php script is run, the values are put to the Spreadsheet as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- **When you modified Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps.**

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.